# Basic shopping cart price rule not working

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to set up:

```
10 percent of product price discount
If ANY of these conditions are TRUE :
SKU  is one of  K27700, K25500, K27950, K14230...
```

This simply will not apply at checkout with the coupon code set up. It says coupon code is not valid.

Rule is active and applicable to the correct website and customer groups.

Similar coupon works when not restricted to certain SKUs (works site wide).

Can anyone advise if I've set this up wrong?

Thanks :-)

Comment: post the code you're using plx.

Comment: I have set up the price rule as above under Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules. I am not using any code, other than what Magento uses by default to apply shopping cart rules. Could you please explain what code you are referring to? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check out this page that Magento has published on this problem http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tip-applying-promotion-to-multiple-skus.  I can't really tell from the snippet that you provided but it appears as though there are some issues with the syntax that you are using.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That put me in the right direction to fix it, now it works. I had to change it to:

`If ANY of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND in the cart with ANY of these conditions true: 
SKU is one of K27700, K25500, K27950, K14230... ` Much appreciated!